# Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument:: After 9 hours

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for a timer with a "Start" "Stop" and "Reset" button. The timer will also change from green to yellow to red as the timer continues. The time at which the colors change is determined by a category chosen from a drop down list. The timer is intended to continue for multiple days if necessary. Usually this is not a problem.

I got the "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" after the timer had been running for about 9 hours.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim NextTick As Date, t As Date, PreviousTimerValue As Date

Sub StartTime_D()

PreviousTimerValue = Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value
t = Time

Call ExcelStopWatch_D

End Sub 'StartTime_D()

Private Sub ExcelStopWatch_D()


Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Time - t + PreviousTimerValue, "[h]:mm:ss")

NextTick = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

If StopWatch.Range("E6") = "Anodized" Then

    If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("B3") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("B4") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
        End With
    Else
        If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("B4") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("B5") Then
            With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yellow
            End With
        Else
            If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("B5") Then
                With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If

End If

If StopWatch.Range("E6") = "Flex" Then

    If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("D3") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("D4") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
        End With
    Else
        If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("D4") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("D5") Then
            With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yellow
            End With
        Else
            If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("D5") Then
                With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If

End If

If StopWatch.Range("E6") = "Glass PRF" Then

    If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("F3") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("F4") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
        End With
    Else
        If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("F4") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("F5") Then
            With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yellow
            End With
        Else
            If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("F5") Then
                With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If

End If

If StopWatch.Range("E6") = "Lineal Outage" Then

    If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("H3") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("H4") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
        End With
    Else
        If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("H4") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("H5") Then
            With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yellow
            End With
        Else
            If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("H5") Then
                With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If

End If

If StopWatch.Range("E6") = "Paint" Then

    If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("J3") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("J4") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
        End With
    Else
        If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("J4") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("J5") Then
            With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yellow
            End With
        Else
            If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("J5") Then
                With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If

End If

If StopWatch.Range("E6") = "Quality Engr." Then

    If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("L3") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("L4") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
        End With
    Else
        If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("L4") And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value <= Sheets("Calculations").Range("L5") Then
            With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yellow
            End With
        Else
            If Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > Sheets("Calculations").Range("L5") Then
                With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If

End If

Application.OnTime NextTick, "ExcelStopWatch_D"

End Sub 'ExcelStopWatch_D()

Sub StopClock_D()

On Error Resume Next

Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelStopWatch_D", schedule:=False

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub 'StopClock_D()

Sub Reset_D()

On Error Resume Next

With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox_D")
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End With

If Sheets("DataCollection").Range("C3") = "" And Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("DataCollection").Range("B3").Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    Sheets("DataCollection").Range("C3").Value = Sheets("StopWatch").Range("E6").Value
    Sheets("DataCollection").Range("C3").Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value
Else
    Sheets("DataCollection").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    Sheets("DataCollection").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("StopWatch").Range("E6").Value
    Sheets("DataCollection").Range("C2").Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value
End If

Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelStopWatch_D", schedule:=False

On Error GoTo 0

'Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value = Format(0, "hh:mm:ss")
Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(0, "[h]:mm:ss")

End Sub 'Reset_D()
```

When debugged, I am directed to this line:

**Sheets("Calculations").Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Time - t + PreviousTimerValue, "[h]:mm:ss")**

Comment: Maybe `Time - t + PreviousTimerValue` evaluates to a negative value.

Comment: @BigBen Do you have a recommendations on how to fix this? The timer still counts upward, but I don't know why it bugs out after a couple hours.

Comment: Well for starters I'd `Debug.Print  Time - t + PreviousTimerValue` to see what it evaluates to when the error occurs.

Comment: when I do that I get the following: ```12:00:00 AM 
12:00:00 AM 
12:00:00 AM 
12:00:01 AM 
12:00:01 AM 
12:00:01 AM 
12:00:01 AM 
12:00:01 AM 
12:00:02 AM 
12:00:02 AM 
12:00:02 AM 
12:00:03 AM 
12:00:03 AM 
12:00:03 AM 
12:00:04 AM 
12:00:04 AM 
12:00:04 AM 
12:00:05 AM 
12:00:05 AM 
12:00:05 AM 
12:00:06 AM 
12:00:06 AM 
12:00:06 AM 
12:00:07 AM 
12:00:07 AM 
12:00:07 AM 
12:00:08 AM 
12:00:08 AM 
12:00:08 AM 
``` after running for 8 seconds

Comment: Honestly you probably shouldn't be using `Text` anyway, and should be just applying the correct `.NumberFormat` to the cell in question.